# npm ERR! addLocal Could not install

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

When attempting to `npm install` or install with Yarn, it unsuccessfully looks for package.json in the directory above.

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/user/Developer
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node6-lts/6.9.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -21
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/Developer/npm-debug.log
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Please check the descriptions in the tags before posting - [yarn] is for Apache Hadoop's YARN tool, not the package manager. I've retagged this for you for now.

Comment: Could you also include your `package.json` and `npm-debug.log`?

Comment: If you've got combination with ```addLocal``` error with ```ENOENT: no such file or directory``` where you'll see that npm trying to access ```folder\dependency``` skipping node_modules - you could also check dependency managers. For me nearly same error was caused with ```shrinkwrap``` and ```@types/node```.